# Unity 3D editor with JetBrains Rider as an IDE on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, unity3d

I got Unity up and running on ubuntu. same with JetBrains Rider (which correctly recognized my mono and .net sdks as it was starting up.)

**I'd now like to open my new unity project in rider and set up unity to have rider be it's default editor.**

On windows and mac I know this is a fairly straightforward [process](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/30/getting-started-rider-unity/) but contrary to windows on linux, jetbrains IDEs are not system-declared so Unity on it's own has no way of knowing that Rider is installed. So from the get-go Rider's method for binding to unity and vice versa does not exist on ubuntu.

the correct (non-snap) method of installing on ubuntu is by extracting a tar.gz and running it's shell script.

I imagine it is still very much possible to accomplish anyways but more manually?

**what are these manual steps?**

For one, searching my Unity project's folder there is not an `.sln` as this : https://gist.github.com/benjaminjackman/9d2284dff3e5098a2df0 seems to indicate is what I should open in Rider.

I have tried adding a square to my project and compiling and running it, it ran but there was still no `.sln` file.

I also tried turning on "Generate All .csproj files" in the Unity Preferences to see if it generated the `.sln` file on save or build then but still no.

This is the "external tools" tab view in the Preferences that I see :

[image: ubuntu unity 3d engine preference screen]

but on the documentation website : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html#External-Tools

it shows something with much more options :

notice the "Add .unityproj's to .sln" option that I would very much like to have.

For making Unity open C# scripts in Rider I pointed to Rider's `.sh` file in bin and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this no longer happens in ubuntu 20.04 with the alpha build of unity 2020 and with rider 2020.

Rider is autodetected in a dropdown list :

[image: unity dropdown for editors]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JetBrains Rider unity package is installed and updated to the last version, then in the drop-down locate the rider.sh file (it's located on [the folder you installed Rider in]/bin
and it should automatically recognize the IDE